# webpack adds extra styles for focus-visible pseudo-class

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader

I've added below styles to scss file

```
.element:focus-visible {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

After webpack compilation generated css has below code.Extra class selector is getting added for focus-visible

```
.element.focus-visible {
  background-color: pink;
}
.element:focus-visible {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Basic configuration is added for scss-loader and css-loader in webpack config file

post-css-loader is adding this extra class.is there any option to disable it